# how to find congruence class modulo a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $p(x)=x^2+x+2$ in $F3[x]$.

Find:

(i)$(\alpha + 1)(\alpha + 2)$

(ii) The inverse of $2\alpha + 1$

for $i$,  I multiplied out and found that

$$(\alpha + 1)(\alpha + 2)=(\alpha^2+ 3\alpha + 2)$$

and then simplify to $4\alpha + 4$ and then  $\alpha + 1$,

or would it just be  that

$(\alpha^2+ 3\alpha + 2)$ becomes $(\alpha + 4)$ in $F3$

I'm just really confused on this question in general, any help please?
The second part I am confused on how to start.

Comment: The unspoken requirement is to represent each expression in $\alpha$ as a linear combination of $1$ and $\alpha$, via Euclidean division. The standard, mindless, way to find the inverse of $2\alpha+1$ would be to work through the Euclidean Algorithm for gcd. In a case like this, it’s *far* easier to write down the successive powers of $\alpha$ (I’m assuming that there are $8$ distinct ones here), and pick out the exponent for $\alpha+1$, and then you know the reciprocal of $\alpha+1$, presto pronto.